# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nonetype

I keep getting this error for like 20 "if ntext[x] in dictionary:". The program converts text talk into english.

```
import csv
def CreateDictionary ():
    fo = open("textToEnglish2014.csv" , "r")
    dictonary = {}
    reader = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in reader:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
        return dictionary

def main():
    dictionary = CreateDictionary()
    y = "y"
    while y == "y":
        text = input("Enter text to which you would like conversion: ")
        text = text.lower()
        ntext = text.split(" ")
        new_text = ""
        x = 0
        while x < len(ntext):
            if ntext[x] in dictionary:
                new_text = new_text + dictionary[ntext[x]] + " "
            else:
                export = export + "NF "
            x += 1
        print (new_text)
        y = input("Continue conversion? y or q ")

main()
```

Comment: Is the "return" in CreateDictionary() meant to be indented like that? If so, CreateDictionary will return after the first line.

Comment: And it will only return the dictionary if there is a first line; if there isn't, it'll fall off the end of the function and return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dictonary = {}
```

should be

```
dictionary = {}
```

note the spelling